# How to register types varying parameter constructor [Unity IoC]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container, ioc-container

I have the interafes and classes above in my project:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T> : IDisposable where T : class { }
public interface IUserRepository : IRepositoryBase<User> { }
public interface IPaymentRepository : IRepositoryBase<Payment> { }
public class SecurityContext : DbContext { }
public class FinanceContext : DbContext { }

public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    public RepositoryBase(DbContext context) { }
}
```

I'm trying to inject the correct DbContext to the objects created from the IUserRepository e IPaymentRepository interfaces:

- IUserRepository -> should be resolved as new RepositoryBase(new
  SecurityContext())
- IPaymentRepository -> should be resolved as new
  RepositoryBase(new FinanceContext())

I tried the code below without success:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, RepositoryBase<User>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<SecurityContext>()));
```

... and got the following error

> The type 'RepositoryBase' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo'
>   in the generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer,
>   params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from 'RepositoryBase' to
>   'IUserRepository'.

**[EDIT]**
I changed the approach as Georg suggested and It's working great.

After eliminate the IUserRepository and IPaymentRepository interfaces I registered the type as following:

```
    container.RegisterType<IRepositoryBase<User>, RepositoryBase<User>>
        (new InjectionConstructor(typeof(SecurityContext)));
```

Finally I just had to change my Service to recieve an IRepositoryBase injected in its constructor.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IRepositoryBase<User> _repository;

    public ColaboradorService(IRepositoryBase<User> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a covariance/contravariance issue, try this: http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct. Your implementation class `RepsoitoryBase<T>` does not implement `IUserRepository` but only its anchestor `IRepositoryBase<User>`, even though since the former does not add anything to the latter, it could offer this functionality. Creating this interface `IUserRepository` is much more than just an alias to `IRepositoryBase<User>` and since .NET does not allow duck typing, you get this error message.

What you could do is to simply register the instance as `IRepositoryBase<User>` instead of `IUserRepository`. Since .NET has strong generics, the former is something entirely different than for example `IRepositoryBase<Payment>` since the runtime is aware of generic type arguments.

Comment: Georg, thank you! Your suggestion solved the conversion problem and from that point was easy to inject the right context. thx.